# Show that every algebraic subset of $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$ is equal to $V(F)$ for some $F∈\mathbb R[X,Y]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Show that every algebraic subset of $\Bbb A^2(\Bbb R)$ is equal to $V(F)$ for some $F∈\mathbb R[X,Y]$.

Suppose $X=V(S)$ for some set $S \subseteq \Bbb R[X,Y]$. Now $V(S)=V(<S>)$ where $<S>$ is the ideal generated by $S$. Now $\Bbb R[X,Y]$ being Noetherian $<S>=<\{f_1,...,f_n\}>$. Now how to create a single polynomial out of this?

Is this be $F=f_1+ \cdots + f_n$? Because $V(S)= \cap_{i=1}^n V(f_i)$..

But one thing is to think that if the underlying field $\Bbb k$ is algebraically closed then what will happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sum_i f_i$ will not work in general, for the different $f_i$ could cancel, e. g. we have that $V(X) \cap V(-X) \ne V(X - X) = V(0) = \mathbf A^2(\mathbf R)$. But $\sum_i f_i^2$ will do.

---

Addendum (thanks to @Hoot): If $k$ is algebraically closed, the corresponding result over $k[X,Y]$ does not hold, consider $A = \{0\} \subseteq \mathbf A^2(k)$. $A$ is algebraic, as $A = V(X,Y)$, but for any $F \in k[X,Y]$, we have $V(F) \ne A$: For suppose there were $F \in k[X,Y]$ with $A =  V(F)$ given, then $F$ is not a constant. Write $F(X,Y) = \sum_{k=0}^N a_k(X)Y^k$ with $a_N(X) \ne 0$. W.l.o.g. we have $N > 0$ (otherwise exchange the roles of $X$ and $Y$). Then for $x \in k \setminus \{0\}$, $f(Y) := f(x,Y)$ is a non-constant polynomial in $k[Y]$, hence has a root $y \in k$ due to algebraic closure. Hence $(x,y) \in V(F) \setminus A$. Contradiction.

Comment: But what is the case if $k$ is algebraically closed? Is the result still holds?

Comment: @user152715 Try to find a single polynomial that cuts out the origin in $\mathbf C^2$.

Comment: $f(x,y)=x$ will cut the origin in $\Bbb C^2$ right?

Comment: @user152715 Added something.